# Can a WebSocket be connected to a Socket Server?

Tags: php, sockets, nginx, websocket

I want to implement a simple WebSocket server using PHP and nginx, and am under the following impression:

1. Once a Websocket has gone through the "Protocol Switch" described in [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455), it can communicate with any standard (non-"Web") socket server.
2. According to the [nginx manual](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html), nginx can perform the aforementioned "Protocol Switch".

With this in mind, I tried the following simple implementation consisting of a JavaScript client, an nginx configuration, and a PHP server (see below).

Results:

- The PHP server receives the WebSocket HTTP header containing `Connection: upgrade`, `Sec-WebSocket-Key: ***` and similar fields. I assume this is good.
- However, the `onopen` event is never triggered on the client, and this is where I'm stuck.

Questions:

- Have I misunderstood some details, or maybe the entire concept of how this works?
- How can I make my code examples work?

**The Javascript client:**

```
function socket() {
 
  var ws = new WebSocket("ws://socket/hello/");
  
  ws.onopen = function() {
    ws.send("Hello, World!");
  };
  
  ws.onmessage = function(event) { 
    console.log(event.data);
  };
  
}

socket();
```

**The nginx configuration:**

```
  server {
    location /hello/ {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:10000;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }   
    server_name socket;
    root socket;
  }
```

**The PHP server:**

(Implemented exactly as described in Example #1 in the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/sockets.examples.php), only changing `$address` to `127.0.0.1`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can, but only if the socket server implements the websocket protocol.  If you are asking if it can be used as a generic TCP or UDP socket, it cannot.  Full stop.

Comment: Is it possible to make a simple implementation that requires only a couple of hundred lines of code (like the obsolete http://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/)? Or do you inevitably end up with thousands of lines (like http://socketo.me)?

Comment: its a complicated standard.   depends on what underlying systems you build on top of as to how complicated it is.   To build it on top of an existing web server, maybe many hundreds.  From scratch?  Yeah, thousands.   And lots of RFCs to read.

Comment: To hell with that. I'll use a library.